# Update textBox2 text while typing text in textBox1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 text boxes (like currency convertor)

I want to update textbox2 while I type in textbox1 which jquery function should I use?

```
CREDIT: <input type="text" id="credit"/>

USD: <input type="text" id="usd"/>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#credit").change(function () {
           $("#usd").val((parseInt($("#credit").val(), 10) * 2));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ysC3/

Right now the usd val updates on lost focus.

What function can I use to update the USD val while I type in credit text box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use the "change" event, but rather the "input" event to find out if the content has changed.

```
$("#credit").on('input', function () {
       $("#usd").val((parseInt($(this).val(), 10) * 2));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it's what you needed :)

Comment: `keyup` will fire an event if any keys are pressed (even ctrl, shift, etc.). The `input` event will only fire on content change, so it's more appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

The `input` event is much more inclusive/responsive than the `change` event:

```
$("#credit").on('input', function () {
    $( "#usd" ).val( +this.value * 2 );
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/9ysC3/5/)

You may also adjust you markup so it can do some validation:

```
CREDIT:
<input type="number" id="credit" />
<br/>USD:
<input type="number" id="usd" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 1):

USe this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ysC3/2/

```
$("#credit").keypress(function () {
$("#usd").val((parseInt($("#credit").val(), 10) * 2));
});
```

On `keyup` is just as effective.

Answer (score 0):

As written in aa333's answer, but replace keypress with keyup to make the update more responsive:

```
$("#credit").keypress(function () {
  $("#usd").val((parseInt($("#credit").val(), 10) * 2));
});
```